# How to dump the data of some SQLite3 tables?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, export, database-table

How do I dump the data, and only the data, not the schema, of some SQLite3 tables of a database (not all the tables)?
The dump should be in SQL format, as it should be easily re-entered into the database later and should be done from the command line. Something like

```
sqlite3 db .dump
```

but without dumping the schema and selecting which tables to dump.

Comment: To what format? Anything in particular, or are your just looking for a human readable backup? Please specify.

Comment: I want to dump to SQL format, so that I can restore it easily. I've added that information to the main question.

Answer (score 240):

You're not saying what you wish to do with the dumped file.

To get a CSV file (which can be imported into almost everything)

```
.mode csv 
-- use '.separator SOME_STRING' for something other than a comma.
.headers on 
.out file.csv 
select * from MyTable;
```

To get an SQL file (which can be reinserted into a different SQLite database)

```
.mode insert <target_table_name>
.out file.sql 
select * from MyTable;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically using SQL statements? I can see how to do it using the interpreter, but what if I wanted to write a script?

Comment: You can put your statements in a file (e.g. sample.txt) and then invoke it using: sqlite3 db.sq3 < sample.txt

Comment: "*Or use the .once command instead of .output and output will only be redirected for the single next command before reverting to the console. Use .output with no arguments to begin writing to standard output again.*" [SQLite docs](https://sqlite.org/cli.html)

Comment: You can also inline the statements, e.g. `sqlite3 input.db ".mode insert <target_table_name>" "select * from MyTable;"`

Answer (score 198):

You can do this getting difference of .schema and .dump commands. for example with grep:

```
sqlite3 some.db .schema > schema.sql
sqlite3 some.db .dump > dump.sql
grep -vx -f schema.sql dump.sql > data.sql
```

`data.sql` file will contain only data without schema, something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO "table1" VALUES ...;
...
INSERT INTO "table2" VALUES ...;
...
COMMIT;
```

Comment: @anurageldorado it's plain sql. just run `sqlite3 some.db < data.sql`

Comment: For some rasson not work for me. I need uses around. `sqlite3 storage/db/jobs.s3db .schema jobs > schema.sql` not work, but `echo '.schema' jobs | sqlite3 storage/db/jobs.s3db > schema.sql` work fine

Comment: It seemed like a good solution, but in my case most of the lines are actually getting removed by grep. The .schema command generates the schema of each table on multiple lines, so there is a line containing only `);`, and the grep removes all of the lines containing `);` Adding the `-x` option to grep resolves this problem.

Answer (score 44):

You can specify one or more table arguments to the .dump special command, e.g.`sqlite3 db ".dump 'table1' 'table2'"`.

Comment: when I add multiple table names as you mentioned, it gives me this output: Usage: .dump ?--preserve-rowids? ?LIKE-PATTERN?

Comment: @mwm I'm observing the same problem in `sqlite3 3.31.1 (2020/01/27)`. The [changelog](https://sqlite.org/changes.html) says nothing about that. (By the way, `--preserve-rowids` does work but is not documented at all.)

Comment: Same problem. Sqlite 3.11.0

Answer (score 38):

Not the best way, but at lease does not need external tools (except grep, which is standard on *nix boxes anyway)

```
sqlite3 database.db3 .dump | grep '^INSERT INTO "tablename"'
```

but you do need to do this command for each table you are looking for though.

Note that this does not include schema.

Comment: I used `sqlite3 Database.s3db .dump`

Comment: This will break if those inserts have newlines in the values. Better use `grep -v '^CREATE'` as suggested in one of the other answers

Comment: using `grep -v '^CREATE;` will break if the `CREATE` statements have line breaks in them (which they sometimes do). Best, IMO, is not to automatically strip out the `CREATE` statements at all, but manually edit them out. Just use whatever text editor you need, and search for `CREATE` and manually remove those statements. As long as the database isn't huge (and since you're using sqlite, I'd guess it's note), then this is pretty simple.

Comment: but the grep of the create will also take the create from the views. how can i remove that?

Answer (score 16):

Any answer which suggests using grep to exclude the `CREATE` lines or just grab the `INSERT` lines from the `sqlite3 $DB .dump` output will fail badly.  The `CREATE TABLE` commands list one column per line (so excluding `CREATE` won't get all of it), and values on the `INSERT` lines can have embedded newlines (so you can't grab just the `INSERT` lines).

```
for t in $(sqlite3 $DB .tables); do
    echo -e ".mode insert $t\nselect * from $t;"
done | sqlite3 $DB > backup.sql
```

Tested on sqlite3 version 3.6.20.

If you want to exclude certain tables you can filter them with `$(sqlite $DB .tables | grep -v -e one -e two -e three)`, or if you want to get a specific subset replace that with `one two three`.

Answer (score 10):

As an improvement to Paul Egan's answer, this can be accomplished as follows:

```
sqlite3 database.db3 '.dump "table1" "table2"' | grep '^INSERT'
```

--or--

```
sqlite3 database.db3 '.dump "table1" "table2"' | grep -v '^CREATE'
```

The caveat, of course, is that you have to have grep installed.

Comment: I like this one. As an added bonus, it still works if you have a dumped SQL file hanging around, just `cat database.sql | grep '^INSERT' > database_inserts.sql` (same for schema, replace with `grep '^CREATE'`

Comment: @trisweb, of course you mean `grep '^INSERT' < database.sql > database_inserts.sql` that `cat` is superfluous

Comment: Nothing superfluous about it. The `cat` costs basically nothing to execute and makes the chain of input to output much clearer. Of course, you could also write `< database.sql grep '^INSERT' ...` but an explicit pipe is much easier to read.

Comment: when I add multiple table names as you mentioned, it gives me this output: Usage: .dump ?--preserve-rowids? ?LIKE-PATTERN?

Comment: -1: Searching for lines with CREATE is a useless idea. Almost every view or trigger especially, if it contains comments, requires more than one line.

Answer (score 8):

## Review of other possible solutions

**Include only INSERTs**

```
sqlite3 database.db3 .dump | grep '^INSERT INTO "tablename"'
```

Easy to implement but it will fail if any of your columns include new lines

**SQLite insert mode**

```
for t in $(sqlite3 $DB .tables); do
    echo -e ".mode insert $t\nselect * from $t;"
done | sqlite3 $DB > backup.sql
```

This is a nice and customizable solution, but it doesn't work if your columns have blob objects like 'Geometry' type in spatialite

**Diff the dump with the schema**

```
sqlite3 some.db .schema > schema.sql
sqlite3 some.db .dump > dump.sql
grep -v -f schema.sql dump > data.sql
```

Not sure why, but is not working for me

## Another (new) possible solution

Probably there is not a best answer to this question, but one that is working for me is grep the inserts taking into account that be new lines in the column values with an [expression like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/930271)

```
grep -Pzo "(?s)^INSERT.*\);[ \t]*$"
```

To select the tables do be dumped `.dump` admits a LIKE argument to match the table names, but if this is not enough probably a simple script is better option

```
TABLES='table1 table2 table3'

echo '' > /tmp/backup.sql
for t in $TABLES ; do
    echo -e ".dump ${t}" | sqlite3 database.db3 | grep -Pzo "(?s)^INSERT.*?\);$" >> /tmp/backup.sql
done
```

or, something more elaborated to respect foreign keys and encapsulate all the dump in only one transaction

```
TABLES='table1 table2 table3'

echo 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;' > /tmp/backup.sql
echo '' >> /tmp/backup.sql
for t in $TABLES ; do
    echo -e ".dump ${t}" | sqlite3 $1 | grep -Pzo "(?s)^INSERT.*?\);$" | grep -v -e 'PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;' -e 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;' -e 'COMMIT;' >> /tmp/backup.sql
done

echo '' >> /tmp/backup.sql
echo 'COMMIT;' >> /tmp/backup.sql
```

Take into account that the grep expression will fail if `);` is a string present in any of the columns

To restore it (in a database with the tables already created)

```
sqlite3 -bail database.db3 < /tmp/backup.sql
```

Comment: The regexp of the new solution should be ` (?s)(?<=\n|^)INSERT.*?\);[ \t]*(\n|$)`: using `*?` instead of `*` we match until we find the first `);`, otherwise we would match until the last. Then start and end should be `\n|^` and `\n|$` for `-z`.

Answer (score 7):

In Python or Java or any high level language the .dump does not work. We need to code the conversion to CSV by hand. I give an Python example. Others, examples would be appreciated:

```
from os import path   
import csv 

def convert_to_csv(directory, db_name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(path.join(directory, db_name + '.db'))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
    tables = cursor.fetchall()
    for table in tables:
        table = table[0]
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ' + table)
        column_names = [column_name[0] for column_name in cursor.description]
        with open(path.join(directory, table + '.csv'), 'w') as csv_file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            csv_writer.writerow(column_names)
            while True:
                try:
                    csv_writer.writerow(cursor.fetchone())
                except csv.Error:
                    break
```

If you have 'panel data, in other words many individual entries with id's add this to the with look and it also dumps summary statistics:

```
        if 'id' in column_names:
            with open(path.join(directory, table + '_aggregate.csv'), 'w') as csv_file:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                column_names.remove('id')
                column_names.remove('round')
                sum_string = ','.join('sum(%s)' % item for item in column_names)
                cursor.execute('SELECT round, ' + sum_string +' FROM ' + table + ' GROUP BY round;')
                csv_writer.writerow(['round'] + column_names)
                while True:
                    try:
                        csv_writer.writerow(cursor.fetchone())
                    except csv.Error:
                        break
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the SQLite documentation for the [Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) you can export an SQLite table (or part of a table) as CSV, simply by setting the "mode" to "csv" and then run a query to extract the desired rows of the table:

```
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .once c:/work/dataout.csv
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tab1;
sqlite> .exit
```

Then use the ".import" command to import CSV (comma separated value) data into an SQLite table:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import C:/work/dataout.csv tab1
sqlite> .exit
```

Please read the further documentation about the two cases to consider: (1) Table "tab1" does not previously exist and (2) table "tab1" does already exist.

Answer (score 3):

The best method would be to take the code the sqlite3 db dump would do, excluding schema parts.

Example pseudo code:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO ' || tableName || ' VALUES( ' || 
  {for each value} ' quote(' || value || ')'     (+ commas until final)
|| ')' FROM 'tableName' ORDER BY rowid DESC
```

See: `src/shell.c:838`  (for sqlite-3.5.9) for actual code

You might even just take that shell and comment out the schema parts and use that.

Answer (score 2):

This version works well with newlines inside inserts:

`sqlite3 database.sqlite3 .dump | grep -v '^CREATE'`

In practice excludes all the lines starting with `CREATE` which is less likely to contain newlines

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can export the schema and data of `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with `.dump` shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049109/how-to-import-sql-files-into-sqlite-3/77245564#77245564) explains how to import `backup.sql` into `orange.db`:

```
sqlite3 apple.db .dump > backup.sql
```

And, you can export only the schema of `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with `.schema` as shown below:

```
sqlite3 apple.db .schema > backup.sql
```

Moreover, you can export the schema and data of `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with the commands below. *`.output` creates and selects or only selects a file depending on the file existence and you must exit to close the file (e.g., `.exit` or `.quit`) otherwise the results of SQLite commands are output to the file:

```
sqlite3 apple.db
sqlite> .output backup.sql
sqlite> .dump
sqlite> .exit
```

And, you can export the schema and data of the specific tables in `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with the commands below:

```
sqlite3 apple.db
sqlite> .output backup.sql
sqlite> .dump person animal
sqlite> .exit
```

And, you can export only the schema of `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with the commands below:

```
sqlite3 apple.db
sqlite> .output backup.sql
sqlite> .schema
sqlite> .exit
```

And, you can export only the schema of the specific tables in `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with the commands below. *`.schema` exports the schema of only one specific table so you should run `.schema` multiple times if you want to export the schema of the specific multiple tables:

```
sqlite3 apple.db
sqlite> .output backup.sql
sqlite> .schema person
sqlite> .schema animal
sqlite> .exit
```

Lastly, you can export only the data of the specific tables in `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with the commands below:

```
sqlite3 apple.db
sqlite> .mode insert
sqlite> .output backup.sql
sqlite> SELECT * FROM person, animal;
sqlite> .exit
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by retracile should be the closest one, yet it does not work for my case. One insert query just broke in the middle and the export just stopped. Not sure what is the reason. However It works fine during `.dump`.

Finally I wrote a tool for the split up the SQL generated from `.dump`:

https://github.com/motherapp/sqlite_sql_parser/

Answer (score -3):

You could do a select on the tables inserting commas after each field to produce a csv, or use a GUI tool to return all the data and save it to a csv.

Comment: My intention was to produce an SQL file that could easily re-added to the DB.