# How to import .sql files into SQLite3?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, import, dbimport

I have .sql files which have the following content:

```
#cat db.sql
create table server(name varchar(50),ipaddress varchar(15),id init)
create table client(name varchar(50),ipaddress varchar(15),id init)
```

How do I import this file into SQLite so that these are created automatically?

Comment: sqlite3 DB.db < db.sql 
Error: incomplete SQL: create table server(name varchar(50),ipaddress varchar(15),id init)
create table client(name varchar(50),ipaddress varchar(15),id init)

what's this error mean?
I tried both methods
>.read db.sql
and 
sqlite3 DB.db < db.sql

Answer (score 228, accepted):

From a sqlite prompt:

```
sqlite> .read db.sql
```

Or:

```
cat db.sql | sqlite3 database.db
```

Also, your SQL is invalid - you need `;` on the end of your statements:

```
create table server(name varchar(50),ipaddress varchar(15),id init);
create table client(name varchar(50),ipaddress varchar(15),id init);
```

Comment: sqlite3 DB.db < db.sql Error: incomplete SQL: create table server(name varchar(50),ipaddress varchar(15),id init) create table client(name varchar(50),ipaddress varchar(15),id init) what's this error mean? I tried both methods >.read db.sql and sqlite3 DB.db < db.sql...Thanks

Comment: thanks It's working now. I missed out ; and included invalid chars like "-". Now it's fine.Thanks !!!

Comment: @lakshmipathi, if it's working you can mark one of the two answers that answered your question as accepted by clicking the tick under the vote count next to the answer.

Comment: For postgresql you can use pg2sqlite for that, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69293251/1213348)

Comment: Does the .dump command produce an sql file that will drop all tables etc if I do `.read <file>`?

Answer (score 93):

Use `sqlite3 database.sqlite3 < db.sql`. You'll need to make sure that your files contain valid SQL for SQLite.

Comment: Me too (Windows command line syntax). Thanks. Sure is slow, though.

Comment: I got impatient building from a 40+Mb .sql file, terminated sqlite3 database.sqlite3 < db.sql in favor of sqlite> .read db.sql. The alternative is just as slow, it turns out.

Answer (score 33):

Alternatively, you can do this from a Windows commandline prompt/batch file:

```
sqlite3.exe DB.db ".read db.sql"
```

Where **DB.db** is the database file, and **db.sql** is the SQL file to run/import.

Comment: this worked for me, although i ran sqlite3 as a command in the terminal so: `sqlite3 DB.db ".read db.sql"`

Comment: Use `.\sqlite.exe` to load from the current directory when using Powershell on Windows 11

Answer (score 28):

You can also do:

```
sqlite3 database.db -init dump.sql
```

Comment: This will leave the `sqlite3` client running in the interactive prompt.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you export `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with `.dump` or `.schema` as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and `.dump` can export schema with data and `.schema` can export only schema and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-to-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables/77250719#77250719) explains how to export a database:

```
sqlite3 apple.db .dump > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
sqlite3 apple.db .schema > backup.sql
```

Now, you can import `backup.sql` into `orange.db` as shown below. *`orange.db` is created if it doesn't exist:

```
sqlite3 orange.db < backup.sql
```

Or:

```
sqlite3 orange.db
...
sqlite> .read backup.sql
```

Be careful, if you directly import `apple.db` into `orange.db` as shown below:

```
sqlite3 orange.db < apple.db
```

Or:

```
sqlite3 orange.db
...
sqlite> .read apple.db
```

Then, you get the error below:

> Parse error near line 1: near "SQLite": syntax error