# create sqlite database with c# by using external ramin.sql file

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

with my code i can create a sqlite data base file.

```
public static void sqlite(string sqlite_file)
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(sqlite_file);
        string str = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aliases` (`key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`value` varchar(255) NOT NULL);.... "          
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection {
            ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + sqlite_file
        };
        connection.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection) {
            CommandText = str
        };
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
```

so my question :
i want create a database with read data from external sql file like c://mysql/ramin.sql 
what change i must do in my code?!

and data format on ramin.sql file is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aliases` (`key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`value` varchar(255) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `badnames` (`badname` varchar(255) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `badwords` (`badword` varchar(255) NOT NULL);
and evey command in every line...
```

Comment: You could get an idea based on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049109/how-to-import-sql-into-sqlite3)

Answer (score 0):

Open the .sql file as text file, read every line, and plug that into an `SQLiteCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

you can set all sql text in `CommmandText` using `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);  
command.CommandText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"file.sql");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
privat string _dataSource = @"H:\Ik.db";
private SQLiteConnection _connection;
private SQLiteCommand _command;

private void connectToSQLite()
{
    using (SQLiteConnection _connection = new SQLiteConnection())
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"H:\Ik.db"))
        {
            _connection.ConnectionString = $"Data Source={_dataSource};Version=3";
            _connection.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand _command = new SQLiteCommand())
            {
                _command.Connection = _connection;
                   _command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer(id, Lastname,firstname,Code,City) " +
                    $"VALUES(NULL, '{txt_Lastname.Text}', '{txt_name.Text}', '{ txt_code.Text}', '{ txt_city.Text}')";
                try
                {
                    _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show($"You Connected to local Data Base under {_dataSource} Sucssefuly");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(@"H:\Ik.db");

        }
    }
}
```