# import .db file to mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to export my blog on Yola and migrate to wordpress but I am having some trouble. Yola does not let you export your posts, but after lots of digging online ([How to convert .db file to .sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823164/how-to-convert-db-file-to-sql-file)) I was able to figure out how to download my posts as a .db file.

After more digging online I was able to convert it to a .sql file using a program called Valentina Studio.

When I try to import the file into mySQL I get this error:

> SQL query:
>
> INSERT INTO  "BlogPostBlogTag"(  "tagId",  "postId" ) 
>   VALUES (
>
> '8a49866b2d872c90012d9bb4a6bf4767',  '8a4986c9436bcaa201436c2df939023f'
>   );
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> .#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"BlogPostBlogTag"("tagId","postId") VALUES ( '8a49866b2d872c90012d9bb4a6bf4767',' at line 1

Would anyone have any suggestions on successfully importing the file into mySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with one quote:

```
    INSERT INTO 'BlogPostBlogTag'('tagId','postId')
    VALUES (    
    '8a49866b2d872c90012d9bb4a6bf4767', 
    '8a4986c9436bcaa201436c2df939023f' 
    );
```