# How to create a DB file in sqlite3 using a .schema file

Tags: database, sqlite, import, db-schema, dbimport

Our client has provided us with a file named `db.schema`. Now is there a command which I can use to run this file to create a `.db` file in sqlite3? Can I do this without having to type in all the queries mentioned in the `db.schema` file?

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If that file contains only SQL commands in the correct format, get the `sqlite3` command-line tool, and run it like this:

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.db < db.schema
```

Many SQLite administration tools also have functions to import such a file.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can import `db.schema` into `orange.db` with these ways as shown below. *`orange.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049109/how-to-import-sql-files-into-sqlite-3/77245564#77245564) explains it more:

```
sqlite3 orange.db < db.schema
```

Or:

```
sqlite3 orange.db
...
sqlite> .read db.schema
```