# How to create an empty SQLite DB using the schema?

Tags: sqlite

I have a corrupted DB (fake_db_v3a.sqlite) file which has two tables (user & status) in it. To get rid of corrupted DB, I have dump DB schema and both the tables to a separate SQL file (fake_db_v3a_structure.sql, fake_db_v3a_user.sql, fake_db_v3a_status.sql). Now, I want to create an empty new SQLite DB using this schema. How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Er... `cat fake_db_v3a*.sql | sqlite3 new.db` or the like?

Comment: It's showing me the error like this - Error: near "cat" : syntax error. @Shawn

Comment: If you're using a Windows command prompt instead of a unix shell the syntax might be different.

Comment: I have tried several commands to import .sql files (includes user & status) to the SQLite database and it did work successfully for user SQL file, however, I'm still unable to get the data from status SQL file to my newly created SQLite database file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a DB file in sqlite3 using a .schema file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102976/how-to-create-a-db-file-in-sqlite3-using-a-schema-file)