# Reading .sql with python and using data

Tags: python, sql, django

I am completely new to SQL, but I know Python a little. I just programmed Version 2 of another 10 years old project of mine. The old project has a `.sql` file. For the new project, I made same alterations in the database. Now to test it, I want to read the old `.sql` file, make some calculations with it's data and populate the new database with the old data and the newly made calculations. How is it best done?

(I don't know wheter it makes a difference, but it's a django project and there I use an `.sqlite3` at the moment.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049109/how-do-i-import-sql-files-into-sqlite-3.

Comment: Thanks. It didnt solve my problem, but I found a JavaScript that did the Job...