# Exporting data from SQLite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, export, database-table

I need a simple way to export data from an SQLite database of multiple tables, then import them into another database.

Here is my scenario.  I have 5 tables: A, B, C, D, E.

Each table has a primary key as the first column called ID.  I want a Unix command that will dump ONLY the data in the row from the primary key in a format that can be imported into another database.

I know I can do a

```
sqlite3 db .dump | grep INSERT
```

but that gives me ALL data in the table.  I'm not a database expert, and I'm trying to do this with all unix commands in which I can write a shell script, rather than writing C++ code to do it (because that's what people are telling me that's the easiest way).  I just refuse to write C++ code to accomplish a task that possible can be done in 4-5 statements from the command line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just noted.....I did a dump of all the data and tried to import into the same database.  The primary key needs to be unique.  So my script would need to create unique keys?  Or if I strip off the primary key and it is set to auto-increment, will an insert operation generate a unique key?

Comment: In addition, the table structure where the data will be imported will be the same, and I have to export and import all the data from the 5 tables that are associated with the unique ID.  So if all 5 tables have a unique ID of 1 with columns of data, I need to export that into a file, then import that into the same table structure on another system (the database files will exist).

Answer (score 11):

This may look a little weird, however you may give it a try:

Create text file and place following statements there:

```
.mode insert
.output insert.sql
select * from TABLE where STATEMENT; -- place the needed select query here
.output stdout
```

Feed this file to sqlite3:

```
$ sqlite3 -init initf DATA.DB .schema > schema.sql
```

As the result you will get two files: one with simple "inserts" (*insert.sql*) and another with db schema (*schema.sql*).

Comment: I'd suggest including the table name when changing the mode: `.mode insert TABLE`. This will make it include the table's name in the generated insert statements.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest finding a tool that can take your query and export to a CSV. It sounds like you wanted a script. Did you want to reuse and automate this?

For other scenarios, perhaps consider the [sqlite-manager Firefox plugin](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/). It supports running your adhoc queries, and exporting the results to a CSV.

Within that, give it this statement:

```
 SELECT ID FROM TableA
```

Repeat for each table as you need.

Comment: sqlite3 will dump into CSV....this is not my problem,and I can't use a 3rd party tool.  It is a closed system, intended for unique users (not PCs).  The system will use Unix as the OS, hence my attempt to find unix command line solutions.  My essential goal is to export based on primary key into a file format, then take that file to another similar system and import the data into that database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sqlite3 bash. For example if you want to get `insert` query for all records in one table, you can do the followings:

```
$ sqlite3 /path/to/db_name.db
>>.mode insert
>>.output insert.sql
>>select * from table_name;
```

It will creates a file name called `insert.sql` and puts `insert` query for every record in the given table.

A sample for what you get in `insert.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO "table" VALUES("data for record one");
INSERT INTO "table" VALUES("data for record two");
..
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use the `quote` function of SQLite.

```
echo "SELECT 'INSERT INTO my_new_table (my_new_key) VALUES (' || quote(my_old_key) || ');' FROM my_old_table;" | sqlite my_table > statements.sql
```

Comment: Can you give more explanation about `quote` ?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can export only the data of the specific tables in `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with the commands below. *`.output` creates and selects or only selects a file depending on the file existence and you must exit to close the file (e.g., `.exit` or `.quit`) otherwise the results of SQLite commands are output to the file:

```
sqlite3 apple.db
sqlite> .mode insert
sqlite> .output backup.sql
sqlite> SELECT * FROM person, animal;
sqlite> .exit
```

*[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-to-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables/77250719#77250719) explains how to export schema and data.