# Java JDBC/SQLite: Export tables to sql statements

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, statements

I'm currently working with a SQLite database in java. 
But I would like to export all the tables and their data to SQL statements.

I've tried using:

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLENAMES INTO OUTFILE '...'
```

But that gives me an error: " near "INTO": syntax error "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that, you can use outer software, such as SQLDeveloper or [SQLAdministrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/). IntelliJ in Ultimate edition also supports exporting table data.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to export it using only sql you can use

```
sqlite3 db .dump
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389930/exporting-data-from-sqlite-3) info if you want to export only selected tables.

Comment: More detailed article: http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-dump-backup-database-file-how

Comment: So it's not possible to export using Java? If I could run that (.dump) somewhere in my code after the user pressed a button that would be great.

Comment: I think it is not possible. However you can invoke this command in java using java.lang.Runtime.