# How to migrate data in Rails 3?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, migration

In my dev database (SQLite) i have some tables (like vocabularies) which i need on production (PostgreSQL, MySQL). Is there some method to migrate table with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails doesn't provide any way to dump the data out of a database but the database itself can. Through rails you can only dump the schema which already available in `db/schema.rb`. However, I would suggest you to dump the data in a CSV file and import from that CSV file into whatever database you wish.

To dump data into a CSV file follow [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables) and [Sqlite3 Doc](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) or [Sqlite3 Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/).