# Dumping contents of SQLite database that can be opened in perl?

Tags: perl, sqlite, firefox

I'm trying to dump my sqlite 3 file so that I can import into perl at a later stage and write a script that will output the table contents. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: See **SQLite Programming With Perl** at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szJFD_ejKV8

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/199221/162833.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If we knew the reason, we might have a good suggestion. You have the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). :)

Comment: Sorry, I should've explained better.

Basically, in Firefox v3, you can delete things like cookies/history and it the data will remain inside the SQLite file itself which you can view in a hex editor.

 I am trying to use perl to see if I can see this deleted data by somehow figuring out how to write a script that will do this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Why dump and import when you can just 'read' sqlite/sqlite3 files in Perl?

It's on CPAN:

http://metacpan.org/pod/PAB3::DB::Driver::Sqlite3

http://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite