# How to use existing sql lite data base its size is 2.3 Mb in my android application

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on android application.My client provides me a data base which is some what large .It is almost 2.3Mb. Initially i don't know how to use existing data base i followed this tutorial  [tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

for accessing the existing database.But i got error.Here i am wondering how to access this type of large database . Can any one help me.

Here i have my DataBaseHelper class.

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.readdatabase/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "categories.sqlite";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        // database does't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public Cursor performTransaction(String query) {

    Cursor cur = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);

    return cur;
}
```

}

Here is my main class

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try {
        db.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.openDataBase();

    String query = "select * from PrayerInfo";
    Cursor cursor = db.performTransaction(query);
    System.out.println(cursor.getColumnCount());
}
```

}

It works fine in Android 2.3 and higher versions .but it does not work on lower versions .I got the error like.can any one help me

java.lang.Error: Error copying database at com.example.readdatabase.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:48)   at com.example.readdatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)

Comment: here iam faceing same issue give me some sugession..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library might be useful to you: [Android SQLite Asset Helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Note that you won't be able to use the original database directly but only a copy, so you will have some wasted space.

---

Another solution might to convert the original database to SQL (which can be compressed in a zip file), and play the script in `SqliteOpenHelper.onCreate` method.

See this link for a way to do it: [How do I dump the data of some SQLite3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables)

Comment: thanks , i used android sqlite Assest Helper its works fine and simple.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That's the usual way to do it. You can copy your existing DB to assets folder and then, once installed on a device, populate the internal DB of the device with it. What is the error? If you don't post your LogCat and related Java code nobody would be able to help you ever...

Comment: Hi ,thanks for response .i edited my question please go through that .Please advice me

Comment: I see the problem. You should make use of onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods, since they must be overrided for something ^^. Don't call createDataBase() from your Activity, just instantiate DataBaseHelper. Then, inside DataBaseHelper, call copyDataBase() from onCreate() (DB file will only be copied the first time). Your checkDataBase() and createDataBase() methods are useless, delete them.

Comment: I am assuming your copyDataBase() method works properly (I haven't tested it) and your openDataBase() method is useless too (you don't want to make queries on the DB stored in the file, but on the internal DB of the device you have already populated from file).

Comment: The main problem is that I think you don't get the idea of extending SQLiteOpenHelper. That parent class makes a lot of things for you (like creating the DB only the first time or opening the BD), take advantage of it!

Comment: On the other hand, you could make use of the DB directly from file, without copying it to the internal DB of the device, making use of functions like openDataBase(), but I have never done that before. In this case I think you don't have to extend SQLiteOpenHelper because the approach would be completely different.