# How to dump a column from a table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, tablecolumn

I'm trying to follow [How do I dump the data of some SQLite3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables) to dump a table's column in a database. The table I'm interested in is called `certificates`, and the column I am interested in is called `certificate`:

```
$ sqlite3 lbb.db 
SQLite version 3.8.3 2013-12-17 16:32:56
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master where type='table';
table|hardware|hardware|2|CREATE TABLE "hardware" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, vendor TEXT, model TEXT, revision TEXT, description TEXT)
table|certificates|certificates|3|CREATE TABLE certificates(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fingerprint TEXT, certificate TEXT, key TEXT, description TEXT)
table|firmware|firmware|4|CREATE TABLE firmware(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, device_id INTEGER, certificate_id INTEGER, vendor TEXT, description TEXT)
```

When I dump the table, I get the complete dump. When I try to dump the table's column, I get nearly nothing:

```
$ sqlite3 lbb.db ".dump 'certificates.certificate'"
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
COMMIT;
$
```

How do I dump the column data in a Sqlite database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.mode csv 
.header on 
.out file.dmp 
select certificate from certificates;
```

Comment: Thanks bernie. I found that elsewhere, but I did not like the `"` surrounding the entry (csv mode) or `certificate =` (line mode) prepended to each entry because the output has to be run through `sed`. But I think its the best I can do.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you could use string operations to get rid of the prepended text in the query itself. I just tested this and got a nicely formatted text file with column header and then the values below the header.