# Create script from existing database in SQLite 3

Tags: sql, sqlite

Do you know any way to create sql script from existing database in SQLite 3?

Comment: What kind of script? Also note that tool recommendations are off-topic on stack overflow but this question probably can be edited to be not about tools but rather methods.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)?

Comment: I need to create tables and insert script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I need to create tables and insert script.

You can use the `sqlite3` command line tool and use `.dump` to output the SQL that creates the database schema and inserts the data there.