# Create dump file only from some SQLite tables

Tags: database, sqlite, dump

In my `SQLite` database, I got 10 tables which I want to create dump file only from three of them. I tired some of the answers from [How do I dump the data of some SQLite3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables) :

```
sqlite> AM.db ".dump 'table1' 'table2' 'table3'"
```

But I get:

> Usage: .dump ?LIKE-PATTERN?

I get the same error trying:

```
sqlite> .open AM.db 
sqlite> .dump 'table1' 'table2' 'table3'
```

How can I create the dump file only from some tables of my database?

**Edit**

I also tried the command CL closed the question as duplicate for:

```
.mode insert <table1> <table2> <table3>
.out file.sql 
select * from table1;
select * from table2;
select * from table3;
```

But it just create a dump with `Insert` command and not `Drop Table If exists` or `Create` commands.

Comment: The highes-voted question shows how to do this with `.mode insert`.

Comment: @CL. I tried that and updated my question.

Comment: That's what `.schema` is for. An none of these commands supports multiple table names.

Comment: @CL. There's no `.schema` mentioned in that question

Comment: \*clickety click\* But of course there is. ☺

Comment: @CL. I have no idea what that means!

Comment: [Look again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7526055/11654).