# SQLite: Dump only schema into .sql file from command line

Tags: sql, database, macos, sqlite, terminal

I'm trying to dump the schema for `test.db` only (i.e. no data) into a file called `schema.sql` from the command line in OS X without launching sqlite3.

I know I can do:

```
sqlite3
.open test.db
.output schema.sql
.schema
.quit
```

But I don't want to launch sqlite 3. This...

```
echo '.output schema.sql' | sqlite3 test.db
```

creates the empty file but this...

```
echo '.schema' | sqlite3 test.db
```

only prints the schema. How can I write it to that file from Terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: Here, you can find a bash script solution https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/325840/272020

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The shell allows redirection, and `sqlite3` can get the command as a parameter:

```
sqlite3 test.db .schema > schema.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out! I just needed to escape the text in the `echo` statement:

```
echo -e '.output schema.sql\n.schema' | sqlite3 test.db
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI you could also have done

```
( echo .output schema.sql ; echo .schema ) | sqlite3 test.db
```

This is running two echo commands in a subshell and piping its output.

Or

```
sqlite3 test.db <<EOF
.output schema.sql
.schema
EOF
```

See [How does "cat << EOF" work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436) for what this is doing.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can export only the schema of `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with `.schema` as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-to-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables/77250719#77250719) explains how to export schema and data:

```
sqlite3 apple.db .schema > backup.sql
```

And, you can export only the schema of `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with the commands below. *`.output` creates and selects or only selects a file depending on the file existence and you must exit to close the file (e.g., `.exit` or `.quit`) otherwise the results of SQLite commands are output to the file:

```
sqlite3 apple.db
sqlite> .output backup.sql
sqlite> .schema
sqlite> .exit
```

And, you can export only the schema of the specific tables in `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with the commands below. *`.schema` exports the schema of only one specific table so you should run `.schema` multiple times if you want to export the schema of the specific multiple tables:

```
sqlite3 apple.db
sqlite> .output backup.sql
sqlite> .schema person
sqlite> .schema animal
sqlite> .exit
```