# How to export a SQLite3 database from Rails app in cloud9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, cloud9-ide

I have a rails app completely developed on cloud9 using sqlite3 database
I want to export all the data I have in this app into a SQL file 
How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dump the data of some SQLite3 tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables)

Comment: @Brian yes, that's correct. That link has the preferred method.